# Why is non-template base class constructor preferred over template derived class' one when template values are identical?

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    base() = default;

    base(const base<T>& other) {
        std::cout << "base copy c'tor\n";
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t size>
struct derived : base<T> {
    derived() = default;
    
    derived(const derived<T, size>& other)
            : base<T>{other} {
        std::cout << "derived copy c'tor\n";
    }
};
```

and the following creation of `derived` class' object:

```
int main() {
    derived<int, 10> d{};
    derived<int, 10> copy{d};
}
```

The output of this program, as expected, is:

> base copy c'tor
>
> derived copy c'tor

However, I want a copy constructor of `derived` to work with any `derived<T, other_size>`, regardless of their `size` values (although the `T`s have to match), so I changed the implementation to the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    base() = default;

    base(const base<T>& other) {
        std::cout << "base copy c'tor\n";
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t size>
struct derived : base<T> {
    derived() = default;

    template <std::size_t size2> // now a template with *size2*
    derived(const derived<T, size2>& other)
        : base<T>{other} {
        std::cout << "derived copy c'tor\n";
    }
};
```

tested like this:

```
int main() {
    derived<int, 10> d{};
    derived<int, 5> copy{d};
}
```

it again produces the correct output:

> base copy c'tor
>
> derived copy c'tor

Everything works fine, except for the case where the `size` values **match**. Considering the following case again:

```
int main() {
    derived<int, 10> d{};
    derived<int, 10> copy{d};
}
```

with the `template` `derived` copy constructor, only the base version is called, which results in the output:

> base copy c'tor

*I don't want that behaviour*. How to enforce the usage of the `derived` copy constructor, even with the `size` values matching? Why is `base`'s copy constructor preferred in such scenario?

Comment: TL;DR: A template function is never a special member function (copy constructor in this case)

Comment: @NathanOliver while the answer of that question provides *some* explanation, it does not explain how such behaviour can be achieved. Is it simply impossible? I've tried not declaring the copy constructor in `base`, `default`ing it, changing it, and nothing has worked so far. While I agree that the mentioned answer answers the "*Why [...]?*" part of my question, I fail to see how it answers the "*How to enforce [...]?*" part. Would you be so kind and shine some light on that?

Comment: Follow up comment - I just realised that what I wanted to achieve could be accomplished by simply overloading a copy constructor in `derived`... I feel siily